# webRTC P2P chat prevent XSS

Tags: webrtc, xss

I wonder if it would be possible to prevent XSS in a P2P chat implemented using webRTC. Since the messages are sent P2P and they do not pass through a centralized server (in contrast to what it happens when this same application is implemented using websockets) where you could sanitize them. I can not figure out a way to prevent XSS in this kind of P2P application, because as far as I know it is not a good idea to try to defeat XSS using JS in the messages receiver's browser.

I would like to know if there is some way to prevent XSS in this kind of situation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation. What XSS vulnerabilities are you trying to protect against, and how do you "defeat XSS" with web sockets?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the injection of any XSS payload sent by a peer, in the message receiver's browser. I mean that when using websockets all the messages go through a server and in the server it is possible to use an anti-XSS library to sanitize them before they are sent to the receiver's browser